Intercept Thymeleaf TemplateProcessingException
I am accessing json data from my thmyeleaf template. Is there any possiblity to catch exceptions and continue processing if some value is not found during template execution?
<span th:text="${some.missing.json.data}"></span>
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "some.missing.json.data" (template: "payload-test" - line 1, col 1)
I want to complete the template processing, even if some data is missing and just have a list of keys afterwards which could not be found in the datastructure.
Some advice?
I already tried to implement a SafeAccessMap which takes care of missing keys but that is more complicated than I thought, because I have to differentiate between SafeAccessMap and SafeAccessList in my data structure.

Afaik that is not possible. You can either have the data handed to the model properly prepared, meaning you have dummy/empty data for possibly missings, or you can check within the template itself, thus handling missing data directly in the template.
